# SocketTimeoutException while opening New Spring Starter Project wizard on STS running with Java 7

Tags: java-7, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-boot

I'm using the ZIP distribution of STS 3.5.1 for win32. 
I start STS with this cmd script:

```
set JAVA_HOME=d:\jdk\jdk1.7.0_21
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%;
start .\sts-3.5.1.RELEASE\sts.exe
```

Then, when I do "New > Spring Starter Project", I get this error:

[image: SocketTimeoutException: null]

If I replace Java 7 with Java 6 by changing the first line of my cmd script, everything works fine: the wizard starts.

```
set JAVA_HOME=d:\jdk\jdk1.6.0_31
```

Is there something special to do if I want to use Java 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to get a more recent version of the JDK 1.7 (e.g. 1.7.0_51) as there were quite a few unpleasant bugs in earlier releases. Otherwise I don't have any suggestions. Can you see the service (http://start.spring.io) from your browser?

Comment: Same result with JDK 1.7.0_51. I can browse http://start.spring.io from the Eclipse Internal Web Browser, and also from the Spring Browser View but it takes around 20 seconds to the latter to show the page. This should have a link with my problem.