# Failure in creation of a new Spring Starter Project using STS 3.7.2 (SocketTimeoutException)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to start a new spring starter project using spring tool suite (STS) 3.7.2 but It fails and shows a SocketTimeOutException .. I've read this link [SocketTimeoutException while opening New Spring Starter Project wizard on STS running with Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564271/sockettimeoutexception-while-opening-new-spring-starter-project-wizard-on-sts-ru) , but I'm already using JDK 8 update 45 .. any suggestions please?

Comment: does it break for you still? It might be that the service was unavailable for a little while.

Comment: If the problem persists I would suspect a problem related to network access, are you perhaps behind some kind of proxy/firewall? I recall one case where the user was behind a corporate firewall that blocked traffic based on user agent and STS is setting something a little unusual as it isn't your typical web browser.

Comment: yes it still breaks. also, I'm working on my laptop from home and i turned off windows firewall and my antivirus and made sure there is an internet connection , but it still the same error